# "You have held broken packages" when trying to update mysql

Tags: debian, apt, mysql

I'm tryng to update my mysql (currently at version 5.6) to 5.7 on my Debian 8, however I get this error when I'm reaching the last step.

```
cat /etc/apt/sources.list
```

gives the following:

```
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ jessie main
deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main
```

Here is what I did so far:

```
wget http://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql-apt-config_0.7.3-1_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i mysql-apt-config_0.7.3-1_all.deb 
(I then selected Mysql-server 5.7 during the configuration)
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mysql-community-sever
```

The output is the following:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mysql-community-server : Depends: mysql-client (= 5.7.19-1debian8)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I did try to do the following:

```
sudo apt-get clean && apt-get update
```

but it did absolutely nothing.

What else can i do to fix this?

**EDIT**

I dug a bit this "packages are hold" problem, and the command `apt-mark showhold` gives nothing.

However, if I run

`apt-cache policy -o =hold`

I get a (long) list of packages that looks like this:

> 500 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian/ jessie/mysql-utilities-1.5
>   amd64 Packages
>        release o=MySQL,n=jessie,l=MySQL,c=mysql-utilities-1.5
>        origin repo.mysql.com  500 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian/ jessie/router-2.0 amd64 Packages
>        release o=MySQL,n=jessie,l=MySQL,c=router-2.0
>        origin repo.mysql.com  500 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian/ jessie/connector-python-2.1 amd64 Packages
>        release o=MySQL,n=jessie,l=MySQL,c=connector-python-2.1
>        origin repo.mysql.com  500 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian/ jessie/connector-python-2.0 amd64 Packages
>        release o=MySQL,n=jessie,l=MySQL,c=connector-python-2.0
>        origin repo.mysql.com  500 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian/ jessie/mysql-cluster-7.6 amd64 Packages
>        release o=MySQL,n=jessie,l=MySQL,c=mysql-cluster-7.6
>        origin repo.mysql.com  500 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian/ jessie/mysql-cluster-7.5 amd64 Packages
>        release o=MySQL,n=jessie,l=MySQL,c=mysql-cluster-7.5
>        origin repo.mysql.com  500 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian/ jessie/mysql-5.7 amd64 Packages
>        release o=MySQL,n=jessie,l=MySQL,c=mysql-5.7

But if I do

`apt-mark yarn unhold`

Debian tells me that yarn (for example) was already mark as unhold.

Comment: Try this link, it might help:     https://askubuntu.com/questions/363200/e-unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages